# How do I minify/obfuscate react attribute values (like aria) with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, webpack

Using css-loader and css modules, I can turn:

```html
<div className='someReallyLongName'>
```

into this:

```html
<div className='_cxY5'>
```

It's great and saves a ton of space.

But I have aria- attributes everywhere and it would be great to mangle/minify/obfuscate those too to reduce the bundle size.

I want to turn this:

```html
<label for='myLongComponent' id='myLongComponent-label'>Foo</label>
<input 
  id='myLongComponent'
  aria-labelledby='myLongComponent-label'
  aria-describedby='myLongComponent-error'
/>
<div id='myLongComponent-error' aria-live='polite'>{errors}</div>
```

into this:

```html
<label for='idl' id='idi'>Foo</label>
<input 
  id='idl'
  aria-labelledby='idi'
  aria-describedby='ide'
/>
<div id='ide' aria-live='polite'>{errors}</div>
```

Where idl = label id, idi = input id and ide = error id. They would all have to line up accordingly, they couldn't just be all random.

I've scoured the web looking for a plugin to do this but cannot find one.

Does anyone know of anything that could help or should I write something custom for webpack?

Comment: mangling is difficult to do for names that are used collaboratively between multiple modules. The only tool I know capable of doing something similar is the [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts makes sense, but surely we could just do something like css-loader does with css-modules? [hash:base64:5]

Comment: That doesn't guarantee avoidance of name collision

Comment: No it doesn't, you're correct. But with end to end testing, you could confirm whether you have collisions. We currently do this for hundreds of classnames and haven't run into a collision yet (I know this is anecdotal). Feels like the perf gains would be worth it if you're ensuring collisions dont happen via testing

Comment: There wouldn't be performance gains, and I believe the amount of bandwidth saved wouldn't be as much as you believe if the served resources are gzipped, as the amount of repeated strings would be comparable before and after mangling.

Comment: And a tool for mangling attributes would not be production-ready if it couldn't guarantee avoidance of name collision. That's a hard necessity for webpack plugins, which is likely why you're not finding one.